# Create callback and wait to complete inside a loop in Angular test

Tags: angular, unit-testing

Given a number an number of images in a component it is expected to create a test that check if all images a loaded.

After some research I manage to arrive in some results but I keep getting bitten by asynchronicity.

```js
  it('should load all images', () => {
    const element: HTMLElement = fixture.nativeElement;
    const imageElements = element.querySelectorAll('img');

    imageElements.forEach((item) => {
      const image = item as HTMLImageElement

      image.onload = () => {
        const rect = image.getBoundingClientRect();
        expect(rect.height).toBeGreaterThan(0);
        expect(rect.width).toBeGreaterThan(0);
      }
    });
  });
```

That's the gist of what I'm doing.
I tried to use `done`, `Promise`, `waitForAsync` and some other stuff, but all and up not working or getting "Spec has no expectations" or "done is called multiple times" in the console.

I know the problem is the loop and if I tested only one item it would works.

But I want to learn how to make that loop work.

Comment: I’d expect a fakeAsync on the it() and a tick inside the onload at least?

Comment: tried and putting the tick inside the onload I got `Error: The code should be running in the fakeAsync zone to call this function`

Comment: Soo.. you need to wrap the callback inside the it() in a fakeAsync

Answer (score 0):

With regards to the error you received when using `fakeAsync`, you have to wrap it with a `fakeAsync` like so:

```
it('xyz', fakeAsync(() => {
  ...
  tick();
  ...
}));
```

For you situation, I would try using `done` but only call it on the last index.

Something like this (follow comments with !!):

```
// !! Add done as first argument to callback
it('should load all images', (done: DoneFn) => {
    const element: HTMLElement = fixture.nativeElement;
    const imageElements = element.querySelectorAll('img');
    // !! Get the length
    const imageElementsLength = imageElements.length;

    // !! Have a handle on the index as the 2nd argument
    imageElements.forEach((item, index) => {
      const image = item as HTMLImageElement

      image.onload = () => {
        const rect = image.getBoundingClientRect();
        expect(rect.height).toBeGreaterThan(0);
        expect(rect.width).toBeGreaterThan(0);
        // !! If the index is one less than the length, we are done
        if (index === imageElementsLength - 1) {
          done();
        }
      }
    });
  });
```